# Turn XSD schema into its atomic form by resolving all custom definitions and refs

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

Is there a straightforward way to turn a XSD schema that contains a bunch of custom type definitions and refs, into the "end result" that you would get if you "resolved" all those custom definitions and put them where they are supposed to be.

In other words: Generate the same schema but written as if you were not allowed to use custom type definition and refs. As XML files get evaluated against a schema, I'm wondering if this is something that happens "under the hood" at some point.

**Example**
How do I turn this :

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:simpleType name="STRING_MAX_200">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>

 <xs:complexType name="NAME_TYPE">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="firstName" type="STRING_MAX_200"/>
   <xs:element name="middleName" type="STRING_MAX_200" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:element name="signature" type="NAME_TYPE"/>

</xs:schema>
```

into this

```
<xs:schema>
 <xs:element name="signature">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="firstName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
    </xs:restriction>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="middleName" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
    </xs:restriction>
   </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: No need to do that. You define your own type just once, and reuse it where applicable. If you need to make a change, it is done once in one single spot.

Comment: Yep, but I need this kind of "fully-resolved schema" for other purposes. I realize it's not necessary in order to validate XML files against it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a schema processor does "under the hood" is likely to be exactly the opposite, it's likely to turn all anonymous types into named types with a system-allocated name.

The main problem with your approach is that (a) moving a type definition inline will involve duplication if it is used in more than one place, and (b) it's not possible to move a type inline if it is referenced from another type definition (e.g. a type derived by extension, restriction, union, or list).

It also won't work for recursive schemas, where a child element has the same type as its parent: if you tried to expand that inline, the recursion wouldn't terminate.

Comment: Thanks! After some digging I am confident that there is indeed no straightforward way to "inline" a nested schema. Can only be done by writing your own logic.